# GParted Allocate space on the right side

Tags: partitioning

I have two partitions win7/Ubuntu. I've freed some space on the win partition and I want to have ubuntu allocate that space. The problem is that the empty space is to the right of my ubuntu partition and I cannot move it. How can this be done? 
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the ubuntu partition to the blank space, run sudo update-grub and then boot into that installation, delete the other ubuntu partition after verifying it works, then boot into a livecd and resize the ubuntu partition to fill the space

Comment: From where do I run that? While I am on the USB stick or should I log in to sd5?

Comment: what? from where do you run what?

Comment: The sudo update-grub command.

Comment: you run sudo update-grub from the old installation, then boot into the new one and delete the old one, the use a livecd to resize

Comment: Did that. Now I am presented with no boot options (to choose win7/ubuntu) and a command prompt that prints >grub rescue . (starting to get scared a bit...)

Comment: boot into livecd and run "sudo update-grub /dev/sda" or whatever your internal disk is, do not specify a partition number

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub /dev/sda
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15729/discussion-between-sbergeron-and-george-d).

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks sbergeron for the 1hour 45minute support!

Comment: no problem I tend to get into binge andswering and it's nice when there's a question that requires some thought :)

Answer (score 0):

From the picture it appears that your ubuntu installation is in ext4 logical partition sda5, but the unallocated space is outside of the extended partition.

To be able to move sda5, first expand the extended partition sda3 into the unallocated space.  Once that is complete then you can move or expand the logical partition sda5 into the unallocated space within sda3.

The tips about updating the boot loader are also often required.

See also Moving Space Between Partitions. [1](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions)